# Unexpected 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.' exception for List enumeration, despite List not being modified

Tags: c#, exception, foreach, nested, enumeration

I'm getting the exception "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'" in my code. I understand what the exception is, but what I can't understand is why I'm getting it based off of my code.

```
public static void DiffCircles(Circle original, Circle toSubtract)
        {
            List<Vector2> originalAreaCopy = original.area;
            foreach(Vector2 oArea in original.area) -- **Exception occurs here on the second iteration**
            {
                foreach(Vector2 tsArea in toSubtract.area)
                {
                    if(oArea.X == tsArea.X && oArea.Y == tsArea.Y)
                    {
                        originalAreaCopy.Remove(originalAreaCopy[original.area.IndexOf(oArea)]);
                    }
                }
            }
            original.area = originalAreaCopy;
        }
```

Originally I had been removing the overlapping vector2s by doing original.area.Remove(oArea) at the if statement. I got the exception, and then looked it up, and realized why I was getting it. So I figured if I made a copy list, removed the overlap from the copy list, then just set the original list equal to the copy list after the end of the nested loops, I would be fine. However I still get the exception, surprisingly.

Could anyone explain why I'm still getting this error? I'm no longer modifying the collection during the loop, so I thought this would work, but for some reason it doesn't...

Thanks!

Comment: `originalAreaCopy` is not a copy. It's a variable referencing exactly the same list as `original.area`. So you are still modifying colleciton during enumeration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion you have stems from this assumption:

> So I figured if I made a copy list

```
List<Vector2> originalAreaCopy = original.area;
```

This does not in fact make a copy of the list, it makes a copy of the *reference* to it. Reference type variables only store the reference to the object so in this case, you now have two variables both referencing the same object, the list, `original.area` and `originalAreaCopy`.

So when you later remove an object from the list, through `originalAreaCopy`, it's still the exact same list you're iterating over, through `original.area`. However, you still only have one list *object*.

In order to make a copy of *the list* and not just the reference to it, the easiest is probably just to do this:

```
List<Vector2> originalAreaCopy = original.area.ToList();
```

This will construct a new list containing all the elements in `original.area`, so now `original.area` and `originalAreaCopy` *actually* references two distinct list objects.

Comment: Oh that actually makes so much sense! Thanks!

Comment: This did fix the exception (unfortunately not the code D:)
Because the "original.area" object was a list I instead used originalAreaCopy.AddRange, which also worked

Comment: Sorry, another update- I also found that instead of using a foreach loop, I could just use a for loop and simplify the entire process, since i can then remove the index of the for loop from the original list each loop. Thats what I get for working on my project at 2 am...